# How to do a bounce animation on Android?

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am not good at Android animation yet but I need to implement a bounce animation like this Animation :

[image]

I have been trying with
`BounceInterpolator`, `android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator"` 
and `translate` +`scale animations` but I don't get the effect

Note: It will be much better if you could provide the explanation as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking at is basically only two TranslateAnimations chained together in repeat mode. Since the white line leaves the screen to the left and the right it just looks like it is bouncing. The [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator#public-methods_1) class should provide everything you need. Let's assume the white line is View v placed in the center of the screen.
Something like :

```
final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationX", ...f);
    animation.setDuration(ms);
    animation.start();
```

should get you started, where the (...f) parameter is your positive float value that moves it to the right OR a negative value that moves it to the left on the X axis.

Personally I prefer the [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) Class, it can chain multiple animations together and is very easy to use. f.e.:

```
v.animate()
    .translationXBy(...f)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .setDuration(ms);
```

Same here with the (...f) parameter.
The Interpolator is optional, and just makes it look more realistic.
For future animations I recommend checking the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator) for all available methods .

You could set a [Animator.Listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator#setListener(android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener)), that allows you to perform actions f.e. when the animation is over. So f.e. once an animation to the right is over you can start the animation to the left and vice versa, and  but I'll rather leave you some work to find out how to repeat the animations than do all the work for you.
All I can add is, I would disadvise you to use an [AnimationSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet), which has a method [setRepeatMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet#setRepeatMode(int)) which might be good for your Task, but from experience I can say, this is rather buggy and often does not work as expected.